# FB is not defined in Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-permissions

I have the following code but the FB.login gives a FB is not defined javascript error.

What am I missing?

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
FB.init
({
    appId   :   'XXXX',
    status :    true,
    cookie :    true,
    xfbml   :   true
});
};

(function()
{
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.src = document.location.protocol +  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());



FB.login(function(response)
{
if(response.session)
{
    if(response.perms)
    {
        alert('yippee');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('oh no');
    }
}
else
{
    alert('login silly');
}
}, {perms:'email,user_birthday'});


</script>
hello
<fb:login-button></fb:login>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function assigned to window.fbAsyncInit is run as soon as the SDK is loaded. Any code that you want to run after the SDK is loaded should be placed within this function and after the call to FB.init. For example, this is where you would test the logged in status of the user or subscribe to any Facebook events in which your application is interested.

Try by keeping other initialization code in between inialization and login function

Or keep FB.login code in $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

FB.login(function(response)
{
if(response.session)
{
    if(response.perms)
    {
        alert('yippee');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('oh no');
    }
}
else
{
    alert('login silly');
}
}, {perms:'email,user_birthday'});

});
```

Answer (score 6):

You should not call to `FB.login` before JS-SDK is loaded, `window.fbAsyncInit` designed especially for this. If you move this call to be within `window.fbAsyncInit` function you'll be fine but be aware of fact that calling to `FB.login` opens popup, doing this without user interaction will be probably blocked by most browsers. If you want to use `FB.login` to handle login, you must do it on `click` or `sumbit` events...

BTW, you already have `fb:login-button` which is doing login once user clicks on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if you try to launch the [facebook example code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/) on your machine (e.g. copying the code in a `.html` file and trying to open it in your browser). You will need to upload this to your server and run it from there.