# Facebook FB sharer with jQuery- "FB is not defined" error

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am implementing facebook share. However I get error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined`. However, if I put code inside `getScript` function (in code below)  then it works, but only at page load. 
Viewed lots of answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400457/uncaught-referenceerror-fb-is-not-defined), but was not able to get the solution.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
      jQuery.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
            window.FB.init({
              appId: 'XXX',
            });     
            jQuery('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
        });
        FB.ui(
          {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
            link: 'http://XXX.website',
            picture: 'http://XXX.website/logoroundTR.gif',
            caption: 'MyCaption',
            description: 'MyDescription'
          },
          function(response) {
            if (response) {
              alert('Post was published.');
            } else {
              alert('Post was not published.');
            }
          }
        );
    });
    </script>
<button><fb:like href="http://XXX.website/" layout="button_count" action="like" show_faces="true" share="true"></fb:like></button>
```

p.s.: Second question: How do I link the button to FB.ui function. Any easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a workable solution. Slight Hack.

Removed `FB.ui` and put it in the button `onclick` and it works great.

So for custom title, caption, image and description for facebook javascript sdk, one can do following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  jQuery.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
        window.FB.init({
          appId: 'appID',
        });     
        jQuery('#loginbutton,#feedbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
</script>
<button onclick="javascript:FB.ui({method: 'feed',name: 'Facebook Dialogs',link: 'http://xxxY.com',picture: 'http://xxxy.com/wp-content/img/logoroundTR.gif',caption: 'SandeepCaption',description: 'SandeepDescription'});"> Click Here </button>
```